# Dependent Coinflip Calculation

Tags: probability, bayesian

If I have a coin that's fair on the first flip, but after getting a heads it has a 90% chance of getting heads on the following flip, what are the odds of the coin being heads on any random trial?  Assume after getting tails the probability resets to fair.

I wrote some python code that tells me it's around 91%, but I'm not sure how to calculate this:

```
heads_counter = 0
iterations = 0

while iterations < 1000000:
    if random.random() > .5:
        heads_counter += 1
        iterations += 1
        heads = True
        while heads:
            if random.random() > .1:
                heads_counter += 1
                iterations += 1
            else:
                heads = False
                simulations += 1
    else:
        iterations += 1

heads_counter / (1. * iterations)
```

Comment: The answer below looks correct, but just wanted to point out that the 91% prediction should raise a red flag about the code - If the coin was always weighted to favor heads at 90%, then the heads fraction would be 90%. Because some of the time it is weighted 50/50, the heads fraction *must* therefore be < 90%.

Comment: Remember *every* time you call random.random() you are "flipping" the coin, so each time you do this it must result in a iterations += 1. However, this is not the case when you get a tails following a previous heads (i.e. following the heads = False line). As a result you're under-counting the iterations and this erroneously increase the heads fractions you get at the end.

Comment: yep, noticed that after reading Henry's response.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the stable long-term distribution, you have:

- $P(H)=\dfrac9{10}P(H)+\dfrac12P(T)$
- $P(T)=\dfrac1{10}P(H)+\dfrac12P(T)$
- $P(H)+P(T)=1$

The first two each give $P(H)=5P(T)$, which combined with the third gives

- $P(H)=\dfrac56$
- $P(T)=\dfrac16$

Comment: this conflicts with my simulation's results because my simulation had a bug!  Great answer